# What does the To operator do in Visual Basic and, could somebody please explain the following code to me?

Tags: vba, excel

Just a quick question.

What does the to operator do in Visual Basic?

For example:

```
For dCtr = 2 To inVoer
```

also could someone explain the following code for me?

```
rCtr = 2
    For dCtr = 2 To inVoer
    If (dCtr - 1 <= 6) And (inVoer - dCtr + 1) <= 6 Then
    Range("A" & rCtr + 1) = dCtr - 1
    Range("B" & rCtr + 1) = inVoer - dCtr + 1
    rCtr = rCtr + 1


End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `To` operator in Visual Basic.

There is `For` operator, where according to the syntax you separate the lower bound from the upper bound with `To`.

While not an operator, `To` *is* a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264568.aspx#sectionSection73). You cannot e.g. declare a variable named `To`.
The other places where `To` is used are declaring arrays specifying both lower and upper bounds:

```
Dim arr(1 To 10) As Long
```

and specifying a range match in a `Select Case`:

```
Select Case i
    Case 1 To 10
    ...
    Case Else
    ...
End Select
```

Comment: This answer was posted before the OP turned their question [into two](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30209450/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

It sets the limit for your loop.
The code:

```
For dCtr = 2 To inVoer
...
next
```

will count your variable `dCtr` from 2 (included) up to the value of `inVoer` (also included) in steps of `1`.
For more options and informations see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

Comment: Pleased to help - If this answers your question, please mark my answer as such!